# Using EventTrigger to call a specific key

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, keydown, eventtrigger

I currently have an EventTrigger which calls the `KeyDown` event, and then uses this trigger to call a ViewModel command using `EventToCommand`. What would be the best way to specify the key used in the `KeyDown` event (apart from passing the `KeyEventArgs` through the `CommandParameter` using `PassEventArgsToCommand`)?

Example:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=TestCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tempListView,
                                                           Path=SelectedItem}" />
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CommandParameter IS the best way, or at least the most "MVVM" one

Comment: @D.Rosado Thanks for the response. If I were to use `CommandParameter` to pass the `KeyEventArgs` through then how would I use my `RelayCommand` (not shown here) to pass multiple parameters, as I need the selected item to be used for this `TestCommand`?

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind one element using the command parameter, if you need the key event data use

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=TestCommand}"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

public RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> Command { get; private set; }
```

Or if you are using a Listbox for example and you want the item, this should do it:

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
              <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=TestCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

If you need the Key **and** the item, that's a bit more trickier, on a binded collection you can maybe combine the use of the described trigger with a binded **SelectedItem**, so when the command if fired you can check the selected item on your ViewModel.